# access modifers in scala with var and val

Tags: scala

I am getting confused in use of var and val in access modifers,
name is var , therefore we can change it, it is ok.
But p is val, how we are able to change the
p.name = "Fred Flintstone"

```
scala> class Person(var name: String)
defined class Person

scala> val p = new Person("Alvin Alexander")
p: Person = Person@139b7bb

scala> p.name
res0: String = Alvin Alexander

scala> p.name = "Fred Flintstone"
p.name: String = Fred Flintstone
```

Thanks,

Comment: You already answered your question yourself: "But `p` is `val`, how we are able to change the `p.name = "Fred Flintstone"`". Hint: *What* is `val`? And *what* are you changing? And is that thing you are changing a `val`?

Answer (score 3):

You should remember that variables are just references. So when you create variable with `val` it means that you can't assign new reference to it. In `var` case its possible.

As you see when you create `val p = new Person("Alvin Alexander")` p will have reference to same `Person` object always. You can't create another `Person` and assign it to `p`

But any person instance has `var name` variable which is reassignable to new strings.

As a result final `p` has reference to mutable `Person` instance.

Answer (score 0):

`val` or `var` works only for next variable (on it's reference), it does not indicate whether variable is mutable or not. In your example, `p` is mutable (because one can change `p.name`). But you cannot write `p = anotherPerson`.